# Filtering function

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

ostream* outfile = &cout;

bool testCantor(unsigned long long p, unsigned long long q){
    while(q % 3 == 0){
        q /= 3;
        if (p/q == 1) return p==q;
        p %= q;
    }
    unsigned long long p_start = p;
    do{
        unsigned long long p3 = p * 3;
        if(p3/q == 1) return false;
        p = p3 % q;
    } while(p != p_start);
    return true;
}

void genRational(unsigned long long minNum, unsigned long long maxNum, int step, string *result){
    ostringstream buffer;
    for(unsigned long long q = minNum; q <= maxNum; q += step)
        for(unsigned long long p = 1; p <= q/3; p += 2){
            if(testCantor(p, q))
                for(unsigned long long i = p; i <= q/3; i *= 3)
                    if(__gcd(i,q) == 1)
                        buffer << q << ',' << 2 << endl;
            if(testCantor(++p, q))
                for(unsigned long long i = p; i <= q/3; i *= 3)
                    if(__gcd(i,q) == 1)
                        buffer << q << ',' << 2 << endl;
        }
    *result = buffer.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    unsigned long long minNum, maxNum;
    int THREADS = thread::hardware_concurrency() != 0 ? thread::hardware_concurrency() : 8;
    switch(argc){
    case 2:
        minNum = pow(3, atoi(argv[1]));
        maxNum = pow(3, atoi(argv[1]) + 1);
        break;
    case 4:
        THREADS = atoi(argv[3]);
    case 3:
        minNum = pow(3, atoi(argv[1]));
        maxNum = pow(3, atoi(argv[2]));
        break;
    case 5:
        minNum = atoi(argv[1]);
        maxNum = atoi(argv[2]);
        THREADS = atoi(argv[3]);
        outfile = new ofstream(argv[4]);
        break;
    default:
        return 1;
    }
    string* tempStream = nullptr;
    thread* tempThread = nullptr;
    vector<thread*> usedThreads;
    vector<string*> results;
    for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++){
        tempStream = new string("");
        results.push_back(tempStream);
        tempThread = new thread(genRational, minNum + i, maxNum, THREADS, tempStream);
        usedThreads.push_back(tempThread);
    }
    for(auto i = usedThreads.begin(); i != usedThreads.end(); i++) (*i)->join();
    for(auto i = results.begin(); i != results.end(); i++) *outfile << **i ;
    return 0;
}
```

That is a program I am currently using to get an idea of rational numbers on the Cantor Set. I'm looking for any way to optimize (currently running from 3<sup>13</sup> to 3<sup>16</sup> with 320 threads (one per core) takes 5 hours and it will probably take 819 times longer to compute from 3<sup>16</sup> to 3<sup>19</sup>).

Is there any way to further optimize this?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not going to speed it up a huge amount, but you are doing un-necessary dynamic allocations for `thread` and `string` (and leaking memory in the process, as these are never `delete`d).

```
void genRational(unsigned long long minNum, unsigned long long maxNum, int step, string *result)
```

Just return the `string` by value. Named return value optimization should kick in (and could give you a slight performance gain here, because you don't need to dynamically allocate a `std::string` each time). I assume you're doing this as you're unsure how to get returned values from a thread. The answer is to use either a `std::packaged_task` or `std::async`, both of which give a `std::future`:

```
std::string genRational(unsigned long long minNum, unsigned long long maxNum, int step)
{
     ...
}

std::vector<std::future<std::string>> futures;
std::vector<std::string> results;

for(int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++){
    futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch_async, genRational, minNum + i, maxNum, THREADS));
}

for(auto& f : futures) {
    results.push_back(f.get());
}
```

For further optimization, I'd profile and see exactly where the hotspots are (which will be in one of your `testCantor` and `genRational` functions). Look at the most expensive operations there (which will almost certainly be `%` and `/`). If you can find a way of reducing the number of these and/or coming up with something that uses other primitive operators in their place, you may be able to get a performance improvement - but I doubt you'll be able to squeeze out anything that'll make the running time reasonable for numbers as large as you want.